# Why does Webview.getDrawingCache() return an image of the content with a different style?

Tags: android, pdf.js

I need to take a screenshot of a Webview.
This is the code I'm using:

```
mWebView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
mWebView.buildDrawingCache(true);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mWebView.getDrawingCache());
mWebView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
return bitmap;
```

This is the actual state of the Webview
[image: This is the actual state of the Webview]

This is the image I get when I try to get the screenshot
[image: This is the image I get when I try to get the screenshot]

Any idea on why this is happening?

Comment: Eh, probably text overlay which is on top of the canvas is not transparent during screenshot -- see how "files" is printed.

Comment: Also (Word styled) bullets are drawn as x marked squares. Any ideas how to fix it

Comment: There is an option to not draw text layer, see if the assumption above correct (e.g. https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/web/app.js#L339) If it's a text layer issue, 1) report bug to webview vendor; 2) create a (CSS?) workaround for your use case.